# How to escape single quote in postgres query via ansible

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I am able to execute simple select/delete queries of postgres via ansible playbook. But if my query contains some single quote, it fails. How can I escape a single quote?

Example

This runs fine:

```
command: psql -U dbuser dbname -c 'SELECT count(*) from table;'
```

I want to run this:

```
command: psql -U dbuser dbname -c 'SELECT count(*) from table where time <= '01-sep-2016';'
```

But this is giving me errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how it would work out in ansible playbook, but there is usually 3 ways to deal with this:

- use doublequotes around the query

  ```
  command: psql -U dbuser dbname -c "SELECT count(*) from table where time <= '01-sep-2016';"
  ```
- use backslash:

  ```
  command: psql -U dbuser dbname -c 'SELECT count(*) from table where time <= \'01-sep-2016\';'
  ```
- use quotes twice in a row:

  ```
  command: psql -U dbuser dbname -c 'SELECT count(*) from table where time <= ''01-sep-2016'';'
  ```

Comment: For ansible, only option 1- doublequotes worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You could just use double quotes in the shell and single quotes inside the SQL:

```
$ psql -U dbuser dbname -c "SELECT count(*) from table where time <= '01-sep-2016';"
# Here --------------------^-------------------------------------------------------^
```